# How to distribute files per directories based on names of these files?

Tags: bash, pipe, xargs

I have camera pictures stored in files with names

```
192.168.33.16_01_20220723150356205_MOTION_DETECTION.jpg
```

I want to move each file into separate directory per date

I found that command

```
find | awk '{print $1, substr($1,20,8)}'
```

prints tuples of filenames and desired target directory

Can I pipe output of this command to command like

```
mkdir -p $2; mv $1 $2
```

somehow? May be with `xargs`?

Answer (score 4):

If you have all your files in the same directory, this is a very simple solution:

```
for i in *; do mkdir "${i:17:8}" && mv "$i" "${i:17:8}"; done
```

Answer (score 3):

You can modify your `awk` program to output shell commands, and then pipe that into `sh`:

```
find * | awk '{
  date=substr($1,20,8)
  printf "mkdir -p %s; mv %s %s\n", date, $1, date
  }' | sh
```

The above code won't work great if your filenames contain whitespace
(or special shell characters), but as long as everything looks like
you shown in your question it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

In your Example, you have given `192.168.33.16_01_20220723150356205_MOTION_DETECTION.jpg` & said that in `awk` , `substr($1,20,8)` gives you the Date , but that is not matching the given file name.

More-over, IP can change and have more (or less) Digits Eg 192.168.33.16 & 192.168.133.116 (& 192.168.3.6) and hardcoding to Starting Position 20 is not good.

Thus, it is better to split on the Separating Character "_" which will work for all IP Cases.

Now, when we have the Date, we want to take only 8 Characters, leaving out the time. These are the left most Characters.

We also want to Process only jpg files & want to mkdir only when Directory is not Existing.

All of this is simple with Perl :

```
@files_list = <*_*_*.jpg> ; # Process only *.jpg files having atleast 2 "_"

for $one_file (@files_list) {
  @items = split("_",$one_file) ; # $items[0] = IP ; $items[2] = Date
  $D = substr($items[2],0,8) ; # take only 8 left most Characters from Date
  unless (-e "$D") {
    system ("mkdir $D") ; # mkdir when the Directory is not existing
  }
  system ("mv $one_file $D\\$one_file") ; # move file to Directory
}
```

This is already robust, but we could add more checks (eg to ensure that file name contains `_MOTION_DETECTION` & there are only 4 "_" Characters in file name & to ensure that mkdir was successful & to ensure that mv was successful) in case it is necessary. Enhancements like these are also Easy in Perl !

Usage:
Execute this Perl Script from inside the Directory containing your jpg files.
All jpg files matching the given criteria will be moved to Directories Date-wise.
Other jpg files & all other files will be left untouched.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me, you could put

```
mkdir -p $2; mv $1 $2
```

in a script, make the script executable and pipe into that script

```
find -type f -not -name script.sh | awk '{print $1, substr($1,20,8)}'|xargs ./script.sh
```

This way you can use what you already have written.

*Or* if you don't want a script, you can use xargs as you said.

```
find -type f| awk '{print $1, substr($1,20,8)}'|xargs -l bash -c 'mkdir -p $1;mv $0 $1'
```

Comment: Not sure how either of those are going to achieve the desired effect. Have you tested them?  The first might work if you add `-n2` to `xargs` .. the second seems to be expecting shell to have access to $ values that are in `awk` context, which it won't.

Comment: I tested it, and it worked. Unless I misunderstood the desired goal.